# MYSQL can't run in MAMP on mac after osx buitin upgrade php to 7.1

Tags: mysql, macos, mamp

I have got this error logs after upgrade builtin PHP to version7.1 but I not mean from this cause.

```
 InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
    InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./shopping/migrations.ibd
    InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
    InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
    InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
    InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
    InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
    InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
    InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
    InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
    InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
    InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
    InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
    161006 20:08:24 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
    161006 20:15:32 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 0 [Note] /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.28) starting as process 8447 ...
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/MAMP/db/mysql56/ is case insensitive
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1802852 and 1802852 in ibdata files do not match the log sequence number 1804211 in the ib_logfiles!
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 8447 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous tablespace mysql/slave_master_info uses space ID: 4 at filepath: ./mysql/slave_master_info.ibd. Cannot open tablespace shopping/migrations which uses space$
    2016-10-06 20:15:32 7fff7b87b000  InnoDB: Operating system error number 2 in a file operation.
    InnoDB: The error means the system cannot find the path specified.
    InnoDB: If you are installing InnoDB, remember that you must create
    InnoDB: directories yourself, InnoDB does not create them.
    InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file ./shopping/migrations.ibd
    InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
    InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
    InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
    InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
    InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
    InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
    InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
    InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
    InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
    InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
    InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.
    161006 20:15:32 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.pid ended
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue after upgrading from MAMP 3.x to 4.x

I just went to: 
edit template in mamp pro and edited the my.cnf template. I added just this line to the file:

innodb_force_recovery = 1

now everything is working and mysql is starting again.